# A literal riddle

Tags: riddle

(First things first, I apologise for my previous question which appeared to offend quite a few, it has duly been deleted)

> To many I am the gallows,
>   
> The place that they will hang
>   
> And every time one is sentenced,
>   
> You drive a nail through my heart
>   
> And why you cut me out to try
>   
> and see through me,
>   
> In the end I am the one thing
>   
> That keeps the roof over your head

What am I?

Comment: What was your previous question?

Comment: @question_asker I've deleted it now but it mentioned a couple of mental diseases (not saying anything bad about them, literally just stating them) and people for some reason got offended

Comment: Oh, I remember that one now.

Comment: I didn't mean for it to be offensive, surely merely stating something is okay?

Comment: I've started a meta question regarding offensive/non-offensive questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> A Wall

To many I am the gallows,

The place that they will hang

And every time one is sentenced,

You drive a nail through my heart

> Refers to pictures being hung, and placing a nail in the wall to hang them from.

And why you cut me out to try 
and see through me,

> Refers to installing windows in a wall

In the end I am the one thing

That keeps the roof over your head

> Walls support the roof.

Comment: Well done! You did that very quickly

Comment: My first right answer!

Comment: lol, you did well on this one, I expect more ticks next to your answers